# How to convert Pacific Time string to local time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I want to convert the pacific time string to user timezone.
Here is the example of pacific time string

**10/14/2021 8:04:00 PM** Pacific Time

Comment: What you mean by 'user local time'

Comment: by user local time I mean the timezone of local system

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript ?

Comment: No, the format is not same as mine. My input time will always be Pacific time, but output should be in user's timezone

Comment: What is "Pacific Time"? If you mean US Pacific Standard Time (PST), it is always UTC-8. However, everywhere that observes PST also observes daylight saving, which is Pacific Daylight Time (PDT). The changeover dates for various jurisdictions are currently synchronised, however that was not always the case and likely won't be in future. So without a representative location to provide historic change dates and values (including into the future), you can only provide a very rough solution. PST and PDT can also stand for other timezones and DST changeover rules.